# How do I stop Visual Studio 2019 defaulting to VB when creating aspx files?

Tags: vb.net, templates, visual-studio-2019

I work on many legacy WebForm projects, and since VS2019 I find I will create several aspx files and populate the HTML, only to find that it has created VB versions.
I have been using all versions of VS since 2002 and I have never had this problem before, as it always remembered the previously created items.
I have tried deleting any and all VB template folders that I can find but to no avail.

I have VS2019 installed on 5 different machines and they all do this.

[image: Visual Studio 2019 - Add New Item]

Is there any way of either uninstalling/removing VB from the templates, or forcing a default language?

It isn't a show stopper, but it is a real pain - especially when I'm on a deadline!

Comment: [dotnet new](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/dotnet-new) -- [Custom templates for dotnet new](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/custom-templates)

Comment: What is your project itemplate? If your initial project is a vb.net asp.net project. The default is VB.  Where do you Add New Item? Based on my test, it will not occur two languages. pic:  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/9Fwd6.png

Comment: Hi Jack - yes, that's the standard dialog I get on a web application, but most of the sites I maintain are old webform websites. These have no csproj file to instruct visual studio on the chosen language/project type, but every older version of Visual Studio would remember my initial C# selection.

Answer (score 1):

Do you not just right click the project, choose Add.. Web Form

..and it adds a form of whatever language the project is in?

[image]

And does it wreck anything if a VB one is added? Just change the stuff at the top of the aspx file and scrub the codebehind/replace it with c#/rename its extension:

`Ctrl-A`, `Del`, open some other `Page.cs`, copy the 3 lines for namespace, class, maybe Page_Load (maybe usings), paste it in, tweak the class name and close `}}}`; intelliformat will tidy it up..

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Unfortunately, when I click Add, Visual Studio still offers me both C# and VB options (compare your screengrab to mine). If I select Add Web Form as you outlined above, more often than not, it generates a VB version. The problem I am trying to get away from is that I cannot find any way to tell VS that there is a chosen language. The older websites have no associated .csproj file, and I have been unable to shoehorn one into the site while keeping the app_code folder usable.

Comment: TBH it doesn't wreck anything, but after you have built the HTML, find the page is in VB, edit the files to make them C#, I then usually have to restart VS as intellisense continues to think it is a VB page.